# how find kendo treeview id or name on checkbox checked changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

how find kendo tree view name or id on checkbox checked changed.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("treeName")
          .Checkboxes(c => c.Name("checkBoxes").CheckChildren(true))
          .AutoScroll(true)
          .Events(e => e.Check("onCheck"))
)
```

javascript code:

```
function onCheck(e) {
   //how find tree name or id here??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must set you tree name if it is as you wrote "treeName" than it will look like this.

```
function onCheck(e) {
     $("#treeName").getKendoTreeView().dataItem(e.node).id
  }
```

Or you can search by UID

```
var treeviewName = $("#treeName").data("kendoTreeView");
var getitemByUid = treeviewName.dataSource.get();
treeview.findByUid(getitemByUid.uid);
var selectitemByUid = treeview.findByUid(getitemByUid.uid);
treeview.select(selectitemByUid);
```

Comment: if i have tree name it is simple, i create partial view ( or user control) that contain  kendo treeview , if i add this view serveral time to one page ,i can not know which tree invoke onCheck(), i control onCheck() function, only once added to view (for some reason) and all trees use one onCheck() function.

Comment: Yes all of them will use onCheck function because you wrote it like that... You partial view should every time take different function for onCheck... So like onCheck1, onCheck2 and so on... With different treeName inside... So only solution is to create 3 partial Views with 3 different treeNames and 3 different functions that will check for id...

Comment: Or try to take angularjs and see how can you construct it to make everything automaticaly (treeName and function names).